# fs.unlink() does not work and callback does not fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

It was working a while ago, and I'm not sure what changed to where the `fs.unlink()` function seems to be totally skipped. The file for deletion is saved in the root package directory, while the typescript file that contains my code is in the `dist` folder. It worked when I passed in only the `fileName` like this: `fs.unlink(fileName)`. But now that doesn't work, and it also doesn't it work when I explicitly direct it to the root folder by using either `fs.unlink("./" + fileName)` or `fs.unlink("../" + fileName)`, or even when I hardcode the path!

Below is my code:

```js
 s3.putObject(params, function(err, data){
// ...
     console.log("Data uploaded to S3 bucket");
            fs.unlink("./" + fileName, function(err){
                if(err) {
                 return console.log("Delete error: " + err);
                }
                else{
                 console.log("file deleted successfully");
                }
            });
            console.log("Before process.exit()");  
            process.exit();
});
```

When run, this code logs:

```
Data uploaded to S3 bucket
Before process.exit()
```

So as you can see, it skips both the `if` and `else` statements on `fs.unlink()`, and doesn't delete the file. It's acting like that block of code doesn't exist at all and I can't figure out why.

Comment: `fs.unlink` is asynchronous. You end up calling `process.exit` before `fs.unlink` is ever reached. You should probably move `process.exit` inside the `fs.unlink` callback, although you may be able to remove it entirely

Comment: Ah thank you thank you thank you. I moved it as suggested and it works. I've been learning a lot about asynchronous calls the past couple days, so this is something I'll have to keep in mind. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using async unlink function that's why it is executing next statement. Use

**unlinkSync** instead.